# Not able to connect to Azure Postgres db from container instance

Tags: postgresql, azure, dns, containers

I have been trying to connect to Postgresql db running on Azure on which I have enabled the rule to allow connection from everyone.

However when I try to connect to the db from the container running in Azure container instance I get DB connection errors:

```
getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN my-db-name.postgres.database.azure.com
```

I am able to connect to the db fine from my mac.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: Thanks @NancyXiong and @Connell.O'Donnell. I fixed the error by changing the OS from Alpine linux to Debian stretch-slim. So when I did `nslookup` from inside the container to the DB host I was getting inconsistent reply. Changing the OS worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you have ensured that you have allowed connection from everyone to your Postgresql DB. You can verify if the ACI can access the Internet successfully. Please note that the outbound IP address from ACI is different from the access IP to your ACI.

Also, you could verify if you have configured your container image to listen to the same ports you expose in your container group with the `ports` property or the correct ports for your Postgresql db service.

You could look at [this common issue mismatched ports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-troubleshooting#container-group-ip-address-may-not-be-accessible-due-to-mismatched-ports) for more details. Please let me know if you need further help in this case.